# How can I scrap data with this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from random import randint

data = []
for page in range(1,5):
    print(page)
    page = requests.get("https://www.propertypro.ng/property-for-rent/commercial-property/office-space/in/abuja?"+str(page))
    sleep(randint(2,10))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.find_all('div', class_="single-room-sale listings-property"):
        data.append({
            'price': item.find('h3', class_ ="listings-price").text. replace('/YEAR', '',),
            'title' : item.find('h4', class_ ="listings-property-title").text.strip(),
            'date_added' : item.find('h5', class_ ="").text.strip(),
            'contact' : item.find('div', class_ ="phone-icon text")
           
        })
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)         
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly, and include a description of the error you are getting, and a stack trace. People shouldn't have to read the title of the question to know what it is you are expecting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `single-room-sale` class is found not only in the ad, but also in the site helper. We can tritely exclude it, since it contains a style

```
for item in soup.find_all('div', {'class': "single-room-sale", 'style': False}):
    data.append({
        'price': item.find('div', class_="n50").get_text(strip=True).split('/')[0],
        'title': item.find(class_="listings-property-title").get_text(strip=True),
        'date_added': item.find('h5').get_text(strip=True),
        'contact': item.find('div', class_="phone-icon").get_text(strip=True) if item.find('div', class_="phone-icon") else None
    })
```

Then

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.to_string())
```

OUTPUT:

```
                    price                                   title                              date_added      contact
0                ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 18 Jul 2022  08168437946
1                    $600            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 06 Aug 2022  08168437946
2            ₦125,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 10 Mar 2022  08056112401
3                 ₦72,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 30 Sep 2022  08171234717
4              ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 28 Jun 2022  08034511039
5            ₦180,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 14 Aug 2022  08182911042
6             ₦45,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 25 Sep 2022  07067964004
7              ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 28 Sep 2022  07067964004
8                ₦750,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT                       Added 05 Oct 2022  08147562407
9     ₦8,500,000Sponsored                           LAND FOR SALE  Updated 05 Oct 2022, Added 13 Sep 2022  09092103478
10            ₦33,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Aug 2022  08155321626
11             ₦1,400,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 07 Aug 2022  08155321626
12             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Mar 2022  08155321626
13               ₦900,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 11 Feb 2022  08155321626
14               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 01 Oct 2022  08037144195
15               ₦450,000  1 BEDROOM COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 29 Sep 2022         None
16             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 25 May 2022  08034511039
17             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
18             ₦7,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 06 Sep 2022  08034511039
19             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
20             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
21               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 18 Jul 2022  08168437946
22                   $600            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 06 Aug 2022  08168437946
23           ₦125,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 10 Mar 2022  08056112401
24                ₦72,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 30 Sep 2022  08171234717
25             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 28 Jun 2022  08034511039
26           ₦180,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 14 Aug 2022  08182911042
27            ₦45,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 25 Sep 2022  07067964004
28             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 28 Sep 2022  07067964004
29               ₦750,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT                       Added 05 Oct 2022  08147562407
30  ₦170,000,000Sponsored     2 BEDROOM FLAT / APARTMENT FOR SALE  Updated 05 Oct 2022, Added 20 Jan 2022  07088739045
31            ₦33,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Aug 2022  08155321626
32             ₦1,400,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 07 Aug 2022  08155321626
33             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Mar 2022  08155321626
34               ₦900,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 11 Feb 2022  08155321626
35               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 01 Oct 2022  08037144195
36               ₦450,000  1 BEDROOM COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 29 Sep 2022         None
37             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 25 May 2022  08034511039
38             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
39             ₦7,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 06 Sep 2022  08034511039
40             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
41             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
42               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 18 Jul 2022  08168437946
43                   $600            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 06 Aug 2022  08168437946
44           ₦125,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 10 Mar 2022  08056112401
45                ₦72,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 30 Sep 2022  08171234717
46             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 28 Jun 2022  08034511039
47           ₦180,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 14 Aug 2022  08182911042
48            ₦45,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 25 Sep 2022  07067964004
49             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 28 Sep 2022  07067964004
50               ₦750,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT                       Added 05 Oct 2022  08147562407
51  ₦880,000,000Sponsored                5 BEDROOM HOUSE FOR SALE  Updated 05 Oct 2022, Added 04 Jan 2022  08124269637
52            ₦33,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Aug 2022  08155321626
53             ₦1,400,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 07 Aug 2022  08155321626
54             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Mar 2022  08155321626
55               ₦900,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 11 Feb 2022  08155321626
56               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 01 Oct 2022  08037144195
57               ₦450,000  1 BEDROOM COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 29 Sep 2022         None
58             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 25 May 2022  08034511039
59             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
60             ₦7,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 06 Sep 2022  08034511039
61             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
62             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
63               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 18 Jul 2022  08168437946
64                   $600            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 04 Oct 2022, Added 06 Aug 2022  08168437946
65           ₦125,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 10 Mar 2022  08056112401
66                ₦72,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 30 Sep 2022  08171234717
67             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 28 Jun 2022  08034511039
68           ₦180,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 14 Aug 2022  08182911042
69            ₦45,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 25 Sep 2022  07067964004
70             ₦6,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 29 Sep 2022, Added 28 Sep 2022  07067964004
71               ₦750,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT                       Added 05 Oct 2022  08147562407
72      $750,000Sponsored     2 BEDROOM FLAT / APARTMENT FOR SALE  Updated 05 Oct 2022, Added 10 Sep 2021  08124269637
73            ₦33,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Aug 2022  08155321626
74             ₦1,400,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 07 Aug 2022  08155321626
75             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 05 Mar 2022  08155321626
76               ₦900,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 11 Feb 2022  08155321626
77               ₦100,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 01 Oct 2022  08037144195
78               ₦450,000  1 BEDROOM COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 03 Oct 2022, Added 29 Sep 2022         None
79             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 25 May 2022  08034511039
80             ₦2,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
81             ₦7,000,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 06 Sep 2022  08034511039
82             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
83             ₦3,200,000            COMMERCIAL PROPERTY FOR RENT  Updated 01 Oct 2022, Added 24 Aug 2022  08034511039
```